How to make key vim keybinding in vscode be mode dependent
For example I've added
{
        // Debug -> Step Over
        "before": ["o"],
        "when": "inDebugMode",
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.debug.stepOver",
            }
        ]
    }

So that I can press o when debugging and step over. ( My F5 key is broken  ). However when in non debug mode I want it to do the standard o operation
I've tried
{
    // Debug -> Step Over
    "before": ["o"],
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.debug.stepOver",
            "when": "inDebugMode && editorTextFocus && debugState == 'stopped'"
        },
        {
            "command": "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
            "when": "!inDebugMode"
        }
    ]
}

but it almost seems like the when clause doesn't work at all because it steps over and inserts a new line
 Though when reading the doc again at https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim I may have been mistaken in thinking there is a when clause. The when clause is available for normal vscode chorded keybindings but not for vim sequential keybindings.

"My F5 key is broken" - buy a new keyboard. Problem solved.

@Friedrich that is one solution
